# How to get the right html colored index of array

Tags: php, html, arrays

here's my simple source code

```
<?php

$index1 = 1;

$index2 = "<span style='color:red'>".$index1."</span>";
$index3 = intval("<span style='color:red'>".$index1."</span>");

$array = array(0=>"Apple", 1=>"Orange");

print_r($array[$index1]);//output will be "Orange"
print_r($array[$index3]);//output "Apple", this should be "Orange"
print_r($array[$index2]);//Notice: Undefined index: 1 


?>
```

I need to get colored index to my output program.
I've tried to add `intval`, `is_int` to convert it to integer. But nothing happened.
What should i do to get the right colored index of array?

Comment: That's not how array indexes work Mate, start over

Comment: Yep, you're on a very wrong track here.

Comment: is there any way to make html tagged index of array, so the output will be right?

Answer (score 1):

You need a more reliable method of extracting the number than intval(). Intval() will just convert anything that is not an obvious number to "0". I would suggest you try with preg_match() for example. Try experementing with this:

```
preg_match('|>([0-9]+)<|', $index2, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Or a simpler solution would be:

```
echo strip_tags($index2);
```

Comment: This didnt' work. I just need how `$index2` is same as `$index1` but with different color. I need to `print_r` the index.

Comment: Check this out:
http://rextester.com/GODFY26830 (Press "Run it")

strip_tags() is the simplest solution for this specific case.